# Error from Firefox: MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, go, backend, mux

I am building a web app in Go. I have had no issues in this project until I attempted trying link my index.html file to a javascript file called index.js using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js"></script>
```

The exact error I get in Firefox is:

> The resource from “https://10.78.80.22:8000/javascript/index.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

I have been troubleshooting extensively. All of the solutions that I have found pertaining to this error have not been successful. Only one post has been go-specific, but the solution was not helpful. I have ensured that the path to the js file is correct.

I am using gorilla mux to handle routes. Here is a code sample:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexGetHandler)).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexPostHandler)).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("/login", loginGetHandler).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/login", loginPostHandler).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("/logout", logoutHandler).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/register", registerGetHandler).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/register", registerPostHandler).Methods("POST")
r.HandleFunc("/clumps", middleware.AuthRequired(clumpsGetHandler)).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/clumps", middleware.AuthRequired(clumpsPostHandler)).Methods("POST")   
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8000", "cert/cert.pem", "cert/key.pem", r))
```

Here is the relevant structure of my project:

```
main.go
>routes
    routes.go
>templates
    index.html
    >javascript
        index.js
```

Please note that the "code sample" above is located in routes.go

And here is my main.go file for your reference:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "./routes"
    "./templates"
)

func main() {
    templates.LoadTemplates("templates/*.html")
    r := routes.NewRouter()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8000", "cert/cert.pem", "cert/key.pem", r))
}
```

Edit: here is the index get handler (located in the routes folder). If the post handler would be helpful, let me know but it does not seem relevant:

```
func indexGetHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.Execute(w, "index.html", nil)
}
```

And here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Compositum</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ if . }}
    <div class="error">{{ . }}</div>
    {{ end }}
    <h1>Fill it out:</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        Name: <input name = "name"></textarea><br>
        URL: <input name = "url"></textarea><br>
        Login: <input name = "login"></textarea><br>
        Email: <input name = "email"></textarea><br>
        Password: <input name = "password"></textarea><br>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- {{ range . }}
    <div>{{ . }}</div>
    {{ end }} -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Type the URL that `javascript/index.js` resolves to into the browser address bar and confirm that you are getting the file you expect.

Comment: @MuffinTop sorry for the late reply. I think I need some clarification as I have never done this before. If I type "https://10.78.80.22:8000/javascript/index.js" into the address bar, I get a 404 error. However, if I type the address to a page that I am certain should load like "https://10.78.80.22:8000/index.html" I also get a 404 error. This leads me to believe that I typing the address incorrectly as I am not sure how it works. I have edited my initial post to reflect the structure of my project for your convenience. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing that `javascript/index.js` is plain text not found page. There's insufficient information in the question to help further. It's not clear what the absolute path of  `javascript/index.js` is or how it maps to any of the handlers.

Comment: @MuffinTop the absolute path of index.js is "/home/marc/compositum/templates/javascript". The index handler has been added to my original post as another edit. Thanks!

Comment: @MuffinTop I have also added index.html for your convenience. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to a backend developer and it turns out I did not have a proper understanding of how static files are served. I had no file system in place for serving static files. I fixed the issue by adding a file server where I handle my routes:

```
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")
r.PathPrefix("/static/", fileServer)
```

After adding index.js to my newly created "static" directory, all works perfectly.

Thanks!